# O servidor não retorna nenhuma resposta ao acessar a rota

Tags: node.js, api, express.js, authorization

[SOLUÇÃO]

Era necessario eu configurar a aba Authorization do Postman e selecionar a opção Type Bearer Token e passar o token

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

---

---

Ao tentar acessar uma rota na minha API usando o método POST o Postman dizia que o servidor não enviou nenhuma resposta.

[image: Resposta do servidor]

Ai  eu resolvi remover o Header **Authorization** que contem o meu token e dai ele acessou a rota e retornou a resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está um trecho do código do servidor onde importo as rotas:

```
app.use(cors());// <--- Pacote para habilitar CORS
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/user', userRoutes);// <--- Ele segue por essa rota
```

E essa é a middleware responsável pela rota:

```
router.post('/posts', isAuth, (req, res, next) => {//O isAuth não interfere em nada. Eu já o removi e o comportamento continua o mesmo
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Foi'
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Por que eu não consigo acessar essa rota usando o Header **Authorization**?

Estou usando o framework ExpressJS

Comment: Acho interessante postar o que o `isAuth` tá fazendo. Pelo descrição não parece ser muito longe disso.

Comment: Você poderia passar o tipo de post que está fazendo? Dependendo do tipo do post, seu body passar pode estar configurado errado. BP docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser Medium story: https://medium.com/@febatista107/como-converter-os-dados-de-uma-requisição-com-o-body-parser-2b5b93100f00

Comment: @LeoCavalcante Propositalmente eu omite isso pra não gerar confusão pois iria tirar o foco do problema. Eu testei com e sem o isAuth e o resultado foi o mesmo.

Comment: Ryan Lucas eu editei o post apontando sobre qual era o problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O pacote `cors` que você está usando, fala na sua [descrição](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight) que requests mais complexos, como requests com headers customizados, podem exigir um pre-flight `OPTIONS` request. Como você não está tratando esse request, sua aplicação deve estar ignorando o POST.

Tenta colocar essa linha antes das suas rotas:

```
app.options('*', cors());
```